# Getting error on ForEach when trying to show array

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have a method that gets a random word from an array and converts it into an array of letters, I'm trying to show each letter using ForEach but I get this error.

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C‎>'

```
var gameLetters = ContentView.getLetters()

...

ForEach(gameLetters) { letter in   //error here
        Text(letter)
}
```

This is the method

```
static func getLetters() -> Array<Any> {
    let allWords = WordList.wordList
    let randomWord : String! = allWords.randomElement()
    let letters = Array(randomWord)
    return letters
}
```

If there is any thing I need to elaborate in please tell me.

Comment: can you print first your gameLetters and check is there any nil

Comment: you can try this to print gameLetters gameLetters.forEach {
    print($0)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is not happy because `Any` doesn't conform to protocols `Hashable` or `Identifiable`.

Changing getLetters declaration to

```swift
static func getLetters() -> Array<Character> {
    let allWords = WordList.wordList
    let randomWord : String! = allWords.randomElement()
    let letters = Array(randomWord)
    return letters
}
```

will allow the compiler to understand that the return of `getLetters()` is an array of `Characters` (`Characters` conform to `Hashable`)

You also need to change the `ForEach` to

```swift
ForEach(gameLetters, id: \.self) { letter in
    Text(String(letter))
}
```